# wget within the server not working

Tags: linux, apache

I can download a file outside from the server using wget,

> wget http://domainname.com/test.php

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `test.php'
```

but when i try to download the same file within server,

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-04-26 03:24:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I can understand the domain resolves to IP and it goes to default path & showing 404.

Is there any option with wget to stop domain resolves to IP.

Comment: Can you edit your /etc/hosts and add the line `127.0.0.1 domainname.com` That should resolve the IP correctly.

Comment: It's interesting that you get a 404 and not a timeout. That tells me the request is going to the wrong server or wrong virtual host. How many virutalhosts are you running in Apache? And what are their DocumentRoots?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to edit hosts file. but no luck. also i can get the file download outside from server. but not within the server. it resolves to ip and searching the file under htdocs instead of actual domain path.

Comment: What version of Apache are you running? Also, it'll help to look at your apache configuration. Can you sanitize it and share it here?

Comment: Apache/2.2.27, sorry i can't share the conf here. i can download the file outside, not within the server. is there any wget option to sort out this ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with wget. My understanding is that issue seems to be the way your apache is configured. Run the command `nslookup domainname.com` from outside the server and also inside the server. What results are you getting?

Comment: I can't see any different results with nslookup msound

Comment: /etc/hosts file modification now works msound, Thank you !

Comment: @RanjithkumarT i can't able to make this work. can you show me how u  got this working. i am getting 404 error within the server too.

Comment: @msound i can see different results for nslookup. i am having 3 virtual hosts setup. can u help